# WooCommerce: Getting price and description of a single product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating custom buttons (rather than the default `select` dropdown) for my `WooCommerce` site.

To do this, I've cloned the file for a `single-product` page into my theme. This file is called `variable.php` and can be found at `theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`.

I've managed to create my custom buttons, but looking to display all the prices and description for each `variation` in the button also.

To clarify, I'm after two things:

1. `variation price`
2. `variation description`

I've tried the methodology [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290648/get-and-display-the-variable-product-price-range-in-woocommerce-3), but it doesn't do anything for me?

Here is my custom `variable.php` (snippet):

```html
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
        <?php
          $html = '';
          foreach ( $options as $option ) {
            $html        .= '<div class="singleProductCard__button">';
            $html    .=     '<input class="singleProductCard__radio" type="radio" id="'. esc_attr( $attribute_name )  .'" class="attached enabled" name="attribute_' . esc_attr( $attribute_name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '">';
            $html    .=     '<label for="'. esc_attr( $option ) .'">
                            <h6 class="singleProductCard__size display--3 mb-0">
                              '. esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option, null, $attribute_name, $product ) ) .'
                            </h6>
                          </label>';
            $html    .=  '';
            $html        .= '</div>';


          }
          echo $html;

          wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
            array(
              'options'   => $options,
              'attribute' => $attribute_name,
              'product'   => $product,
            )
          );

        ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Within each `. singleProductCard__button`, under `.singleProductCard__size` is where I'm looking to print the price fro each variation alongside the variation descrption.

How do I do this?

Comment: How many attribute does your variations has ?? Or how many variations do you have ?? This can get quite messy, as a lot of button may end up getting created.

Comment: @bhanu - One product has `5 variations` and only `1 attribute`. The attribute is for called `size`. I have the buttons displaying fine (for one product, the `5 variations` are printing fine), but can't get the `price` and `description` to show.

Comment: Use this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41015745/8298248) instead of `$attributes` to loop.